# How to get query string parameters from url in the UIWebView in Swift 3 xcode8?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift3, xcode8

Can someone please Help me with the procedure of how to get the query string parameters in a url received by the UIWebView.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mywebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL (string: "my api url")
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    mywebView.loadRequest(requestObj)
}
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

    let loadedURL = webView.request?.URL?.absoluteString
    print(loadedURL) //prints: http://www.example.com/index.php?key1=value1&key2=value2
}
```

HOW CAN I FILTER Key1 or Key2 value?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what are you doing and what did you try?

Comment: Or share your basic requirement which you want to implement.

Comment: What part of the problem are you having trouble with? Are you able to get the URL? Post the code that you have so far. BTW, you should just use the `swift` tag, not `swift3`, since Swift 3 is the current version of Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
let str = “Your query string text” which you get from url
let pageHtml = NSString(format:"%@ %@", "<html <p style= ><style>body{font-family:'%@'; font-size:17px;}</style></p> </html>",str! as! CVarArg) as String;
self.webView.loadHTMLString(pageHtml,baseURL: nil)
self.webView.loadHTMLString.delegate = self
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = true
self.webView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```